# UIImageJPEGRepresentation | generateJPEGRepresentation saves image as nil? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdata, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am currently designing a database management application with Realm, where I have managed to create and retrieve an object successfully. The problem I am having is with updating/editing - specifically updating the UIImage that the user has uploaded. With Realm, I save the path of the image and then retrieve it by loading that path (in Documents Directory).

When the user tries to save the changed image, for some odd reason the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` saves the changed image as nil, thus removing the user's image. It's strange because the initial creation of a data object stores it just fine.

I have tried to check whether the image is being passed correctly with some debugging, and have found that it does so just fine and the right path is being saved on.

Here is my update method:

```
func  updateImage() { 
    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(selectedPicPath!)")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            if profilePic.image != nil {
            let image = profilePic.image!.generateJPEGRepresentation()
            try! image.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomicWrite)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
            print("Image Not Added")
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let image = profilePic.image!.generateJPEGRepresentation()
```

Check this line, whether it is returning nil value or data? If nil, then use following code to test your image store, it's working. Also ensure your actual image has JPEG file format extension, that you are trying to generate.

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

// For PNG Image

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation() {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```

For JPG image

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "example.jpg") {
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.jpg")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saving a jpeg data representation as png

Comment: Yes, both will work, that I want to show you, try it.

Comment: of course it will save but a jpeg is a jpeg. If you want a png file you need to use  `UIImagePNGRepresentation`